# Do spouses need to change name on passport after marriage?

Tags: usa, visa, immigration, identification, pakistani-citizen

My niece is married to a US citizen and will be moving to the US on an immigrant visa in the next 2 months. She already has a Pakistani ID card and a passport under her father's name.

In applying for US visa, can she use her current passport, or should she have a new one issued under husband's name?

Comment: Is your niece arriving on a spouse visa and, if yes, has it already been issued?

Comment: @Dorothy  visa no is issued in usa and case would be forwarding to Islamabad soon, that s why she wanted everything in order just to avoid last minute disappointment

Comment: It might expedite things in future for her to have her passport issued in her married name. It would still include her father's name (as I understand Pakistani passports). However, her application will include all her information, including her marriage certificate, and using her current passport shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Is she even planning to change her name upon marriage?

Answer (score 2):

Change of names post marriage for wives is a practice commonly followed outside US. In the US though it is commonly accepted if the wife does not change her name post marriage. It certainly though makes it easier from the process perspective and also builds confidence in the minds of visa officer if the name change occurs. Could not find anything in this regards on the USCIS website, although found some information about documentation on [other](http://www.wikihow.com/Apply-For-a-Dependent-Visa#Applying_for_an_H-4_Visa_Outside_the_U.S._sub) site which does not indicate anything about the name change